# passing name of member as template argument, referenced by pointer of T

Tags: c++, templates, non-static

How to pass member of pointer to template argument?

It is hard to explain, so I will show a very short code to indicate the problem.

This is a valid code :-

```
template<class T, int T::*a> class B{...}
class A{ public: int mem; }
int main(){   
    A a;                          
    B<A,&A::mem> b= B<A,&A::mem>(a);  // I pass "A" as value
}
```

Now I want to pass pointer instead of value as followed :-

```
template<class T, int T::*a> class B{...}   
class A{ public: int mem; }
int main(){   
    A* a=new A();                           //changed
    B<A*,&A*::mem> b= B<A*,&A*::mem>(a);    //changed, pass "A*"  (#)
}
```

This is a compile error that I got.

```
prog.cpp:18:13: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    B<A*,&A*::mem> b=B<A*,&A*::mem>(a);
             ^
```

I am wrong at the line (#).  How should I edit the line?

### Edit

Here this is the full code :-

```
class A{
    public: int x=2;
};
template <class T, int T::*a> class B{
    T objectA_;
    public: B(T objectA){
        objectA_ = objectA;
    }
    public: void print(){
        std::cout<< objectA_.*a ;
    }
};
int main() {
    A objectA; objectA.x=3;
    B<A,&A::x> objectB=B<A,&A::x>(objectA);  //this line will be changed
    objectB.print();   //print 3
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that T=A.
Now, I want T=A*.

**new version**

```
template <class T, int A::*a> class B{
    T objectA_;
    public: B(T objectA){
        objectA_ = objectA;
    }
    public: void print(){
        std::cout<< objectA_->*a ;  //changed
    }
};
int main() {
    A* objectA = new A(); objectA->x=3;      //changed
    B<A*,&A*::x> objectB=B<A*,&A*::x>(objectA);   //changed
    objectB.print();
    delete objectA;                 //new
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B<A, &A::mem>` is still the correct form. What you need to change is the class definition.

```
template<class T, int T::*a>
class B
{
  T *object_;
public:
  B (T* pObj) : object_(pObj) {}
};
```

**But** if you have access to a smart pointer implementation (c++11 or other) prefer to store that instead of the raw pointer. If you do not, you'll have to abide to [the rule of three (now rule of five in c++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Also, you can simplify your life a whole lot if you do value initialization instead of copy initialization.

```
B<A, &A::mem> b(a);
B<A, &A::mem> b(&a);
```

Comment: I edited the question to show full source code.  May you take a look if there is anything wrong, please?

Comment: @javaLover, do you want to store the address of the object passed, or simply avoid a costly copy of the object?

Comment: in the new version, I want to store the address.